# Windows 7 Icon Recovery

Tags: windows, macos, icons

I changed my icons using 'IcoPackager' to Mac theme and then I uninstalled the IcoPackager, and when I installed it to remove those icons, it says my trial has expired, can you help me out?

Every single icon in my Windows 7 Ultimate, 32-bit laptop is now fked up with Mac Icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing above worked, I just copied the C:\Windows\system32\imageres.dll from my fathers 64bit PC to my 32bit Laptop, and I replaced it with mine and rebooted my computer and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Yes try system restore but if you don't want to i'm pretty sure there are programs out there that will help you get your files back. you could try a program called  Icon Cache Re-builder. 
another way to do it is with cmd, here are some step by step instructions i made to fix it.

1. Close and save anything that you are working on. This command will kill explorer and restart the computer when completed.
2. Open a command prompt in Windows 7 or Windows 8.
3. In the command prompt, Copy and paste each command line below exactly as is one at a time and press enter after each command.

ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache

taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F

DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A

shutdown /r /f /t 00

1. The IconCache.db file has now been rebuilt and your computer should all be back to normal